# How to get data from 2nd Activity to 1st Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

my MainActivity is calling a second activity PopupWindow which contains a listview. when user clicks on listview I need to return that information to first activity (MainActivity). So in MainActivity I have this two methods. the first method calls the second activity the second gets result from second activity

```
 //event listener for authors list menu (popup window)
        authorListImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent popupWinIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthorsPopup.class);
                popupWinIntent.putExtra("allauthors", allAuthors);
                startActivity(popupWinIntent);
            }
        });    

    //fetching result -- author from AuthorsPopup activity back
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String author = data.getStringExtra("author");
                    Log.v("author ", author);
                }
            }
        }
```

this method is outside the onCreate() method. some tutorials suggest to create the avobe method just like onActivityResul() I'm assuming that case it would be inside the onCreate() method. mine is a method declaration. so obiously not executing. In my second activity. I have this

```
//event listener for authros listview
        authorListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paren, View view, int position, long id) {
//                Log.v("author: ", authorsList[position]);
                String author = authorsList[position];
                Intent returnResultIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),  MainActivity.class);
                returnResultIntent.putExtra("author", author);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnResultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

what is the proper way to get data back from second activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to launch the second activity using `startActivityForResult(popupWinIntent,1)` rather than `startActivity(popupWinIntent)` and override the `onActivityResult` method in your first Activity, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("author");
        }
    }
}
```

The first `authorListImageView.setOnClickListener` code you listed would go in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

1st Activity
How to get value

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("FileName",0);

sharedPreferences.getString("KEY","DefaultValue");
sharedPreferences.getBoolean("KEY",false);

2nd Activity
How to set or put the value from activity for getting on other activity

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("FileName",0);
editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

```
    editor.putString("KEY","Value");
    editor.putBoolean("KEY",true);
    editor.apply();
```